# Some Visual Studio files are linted differently based on how they were created, even if they end up the exact same. Why?

Tags: visual-studio

For example, I can create a test1.xml file, put in my code, then save it as test1.proj. It has the xml coloring/linting I want. If I create a test2.txt file, insert my code, then save it as test2.proj, it will not have any of the coloring/linting I want. In the properties and everything I can see, they are the same file, but Visual Studio treats them differently. Why? Is there a hidden property I can edit?

Comment: Works fine when I try it, you do have to re-open the file so it re-initializes the syntax highlighter.  If that still doesn't help then it might be accidentally saved as test2.proj.txt.  Easy mishap, be sure to put your OS into programmer mode so you can see this.  Control Panel > File Explorer Options > View tab > untick "Hide extensions for known file types".

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you!! re-opening to re-initialize the syntax highlighter is exactly what I was looking for, and your second part is a little bonus.